# Android Button Image

Tags: android, image, button

I have an understanding of how to place images on buttons, but would anyone know what is legal and what is not legal in terms of using images?  So I know I can "draw" something in mspaint save it and use it as an image but that usually comes out looking ugly.  I do not own photoshop either.  I am just looking for a better way to create images and make my app look a bit more polished. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: you can use the (gimp) www.gimp.org to make your own images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucky for you, the internet is full with free icon packs, image packs, wallpacker packs,.... that you may use at hart. Just make sure the website really states that it is free to be used if you really want to be correct. For editing images, if you do not own photoshop, i think [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) is the way to go. It's free, efficient and you'll find all the tools needed to edit, crop, modify,... your images.

Here is a list of free icons & image sites you might like:

- http://www.flaticon.com/packs/
- http://icons8.com/free-ios-7-icons-in-vector/
- http://www.creativebloq.com/web-design/free-icon-sets-10134829
- http://webdesignledger.com/freebies/20-excellent-icon-sets-for-application-design
- http://www.stockfreeimages.com/

Here is a link to google's library of free resources, check it out:

- https://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html

Comment: Google provides huge set of icons for all needs and sizes. Why bother using searching for icons on other resources than developer.android.com?

Comment: Because maybe he'd want his app to look a bit different than everyone else his app? I don't think that is something to be discouraged. I just posted a few links i use myself, so maybe if he'd like some, he can use them himself, or just use them for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to create buttons with nice look and feel is to use [Holo Colors](http://android-holo-colors.com/).

Also, take a look at [this tutorial,](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-selector-example/) this will help you in understanding basics of android drawable resources/

Answer (score 0):

Try out GIMP, it has most all of the features of photoshop, but is free!

[GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/)